# Oracle trigger to prevent specified value wrote into column

Tags: oracle11g, database-trigger

I'm working on Oracle 11g 64bit.
Say I have a table named "MyTable", I'm trying to monitoring a column named "My_Name".

When "My_Name" is going to be changed to `''` (before update), I want to stop it and change "My_Name" back to old value. In other word, `''` isn't a legal value for the "My_Name" column.

Here's what I did so far, no compilation error, but no effect, I can still write the `''` value into "My_Name" column.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MyTable_tracking
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON MyDB.MyTable REFERENCING NEW AS newValue OLD AS oldValue
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
v_old       VARCHAR(20);
v_new       VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    v_new:=:newValue.My_Name; --Trigger checks column 'My_Name' only
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    v_old:=:oldValue.My_Name; --Trigger checks column 'My_Name' only
    v_new:=:newValue.My_Name; --Trigger checks column 'My_Name' only
    --IF :newValue.My_Name='' THEN
    IF LENGTH(TRIM(:newValue.My_Name))=0 THEN
      :newValue.My_Name:=:oldValue.My_Name;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem whit following code

```sql
IF INSERTING THEN
  v_new:=:newValue.My_Name;
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
  v_old:=:oldValue.My_Name;
  v_new:=:newValue.My_Name;
  --IF :newValue.My_Name='some specified value' THEN --not allow some value
  --IF :newValue.My_Name='' --not working
  IF :newValue.My_Name='' OR :newValue.My_Name IS NULL THEN --not allow '' or null
    :newValue.My_Name:=v_old; --works
    --:newValue.My_Name:=:oldValue.My_Name; --not working, use variable instead
  END IF;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a trigger. In Oracle an empty string  `''` and `null` are the same thing. So just define `my_name` as `NOT NULL` and you can't put `null` or `''` in it.

```
SQL> create table my_table (id integer primary key, my_name varchar(20) not null);

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_table values (1, 'Arthur');

1 row created.

SQL> update my_table set my_name = '' where id = 1;
update my_table set my_name = '' where id = 1
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01407: cannot update ("ARTHUR"."MY_TABLE"."MY_NAME") to NULL

SQL> insert into my_table values (2, '');
insert into my_table values (2, '')
                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ARTHUR"."MY_TABLE"."MY_NAME")

SQL>
```

If you can't use the most efficient solution because of external restrictions (which I find **highly** questionable), you can use something like this:

```
create or replace trigger slow_not_null_check
   before insert or update on my_table
   for each row
begin
   if inserting and :new.my_name is null then 
      :new.my_name := 'No NULL allowed';
   end if;

   if updating and :new.my_name is null then 
      :new.my_name := :old.my_name;
   end if;
end;
/
```

This will silently convert, `''` to `'No NULL allowed'` when inserting and will restore the previous value when updating:

```
insert into my_table values (1, '');
insert into my_table values (2, 'Arthur');

select * from my_table;

ID | MY_NAME        
---+----------------
 1 | No NULL allowed
 2 | Arthur         


update my_table
  set my_name = ''
where id = 2;

select * 
from my_table;


ID | MY_NAME        
---+----------------
 1 | No NULL allowed
 2 | Arthur
```

Comment: I'm not been allowed to modify a column's attribute, so all I can do is trigger. Is that possible to achieve this with trigger ?

Comment: @RRTW: that requirement is pretty stupid. A `NOT NULL` constraint is the most efficient solution to this problem. However if you are stuck with stupid rules: what do you want to do if someone tries to insert a `NULL` value? replace it with `'foobar'`? Throw an exception and abort the statement?

Comment: I'm actually trying to find which program changed the "My_Name" value... I had append this trigger with an "insert / update" log, so that I can't just throw an exception out.